# URL request times out when app is in the background

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession, background-task

I have an app where I call API request. Some users are experiencing a bug, that application throws timeout error when they close the app while data are being fetched, and later they open it.

I'm using standard URLSession data task as in example bellow:

```
var session = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral, delegate: self, delegateQueue: queue)

private func loadModels -> AnyPublisher<[Model], LoadModelsUseCaseError> {
    guard let keyID = keyAdapter.getKeyID() else {
        return Fail<[Model], LoadModelsUseCaseError>(error: .keyIDNotFound).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    let url = Environment.loadModelsURL(for: keyID)

    return apiAdapter.session
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .decode(type: [Model].self, decoder: decoder)
        .mapError(LoadModelsUseCaseError.init)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

One workaround is to call `.retry(1)` in view model from which I'm calling the method, but that solution has obvious flaws.

Another workaround is to catch timeout error and call the load method again. That is not perfect either as the request will never time out (even when its relevant case).

Any suggestions how to handle this situation? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I have solved the problem putting the following code in my APIAdapter / APIManager component:

```
// MARK: - Configuration

private func configureNewSession() {
    session?.invalidateAndCancel()
    backgroundSession?.invalidateAndCancel()

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.isDiscretionary = true
    configuration.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
    session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: queue)

    let backgroundSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "background")
    backgroundSessionConfiguration.isDiscretionary = true
    backgroundSessionConfiguration.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
    backgroundSession = URLSession(configuration: backgroundSessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: queue)
}

private func subscribeToApplicationStateNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)
        .sink { _ in
            self.moveTasksToForeground()
        }
        .store(in: &subscriptions)

    NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)
        .sink { _ in
            self.moveTasksToBackground()
        }
        .store(in: &subscriptions)
}

// MARK: - App Lifecycle

/// The method currently doesn't move tasks in the background (as only download / upload tasks can be resumed using resume data),
/// but suspends them. Suspended tasks doesn't produce errors, so they doesn't need to be catched in the View Models.
public func moveTasksToBackground() {
    guard case .foreground = state else {
        return
    }

    // Arguments in completion handlers are: data tasks, download tasks and upload tasks respectively.
    session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { dataTasks, _, _ in
        for dataTask in dataTasks {
            dataTask.suspend()
            // NOTE: - Download tasks can produce resume data that can be resumed by standard url session in rhe
            // foreground.
            //
            // Example:
            //
            // guard let downloadTask = downloadTask as? URLSessionDownloadTask else {
            //     continue
            // }
            // downloadTask.cancel(byProducingResumeData: { [self] resumeData in
            //     var downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask? = nil
            //     if let resumeData = resumeData {
            //         downloadTask = backgroundSession.downloadTask(withResumeData: resumeData)
            //     }
            //     downloadTask?.resume()
            // })
        }
    }
    state = .background
}

/// The method currently doesn't move tasks in the background (as only download / upload tasks can be resumed using resume data),
/// but suspends them. Suspended tasks doesn't produce errors, so they doesn't need to be catched in the View Models.
public func moveTasksToForeground() {
    guard case .background = state else {
        return
    }

    // Arguments in completion handlers are: data tasks, download tasks and upload tasks respectively.
    backgroundSession.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { dataTasks, _, _ in
        for dataTask in dataTasks {
            dataTask.suspend()
            // NOTE: - Download tasks can produce resume data that can be resumed by standard url session in rhe
            // foreground.
            //
            // Example:
            //
            // guard let downloadTask = downloadTask as? URLSessionDownloadTask else {
            //     continue
            // }
            // downloadTask.cancel(byProducingResumeData: { [self] resumeData in
            //     var downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask? = nil
            //     if let resumeData = resumeData {
            //         downloadTask = urlSession.downloadTask(withResumeData: resumeData)
            //     }
            //     downloadTask?.resume()
            // })
        }
    }
    state = .foreground
}
```

When you suspend data tasks, the session won't produce error, so there's no need to filter cancels in view model / view / use case / service / where ever you are calling the API calls from. All you have to do is to refresh remote data when user opens the app / enters the screen.